# Should we avoid overusing 'of' in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Often, we tend to overuse '*of*'. In some situations, we can't help it.

As an instance -

> Journal **of** the Convention **of** the People **of** the State **of** Indiana, to Amend the Constitution
>
> **Source**: [...books.google.com/...](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=euMWAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22of%20the%20people%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20people%20of%22&f=false)

To me, this sentence structure sounds a bit awkward and crappy. *How can we avoid it?* Or maybe, we don't even need to avoid it; it's perfectly grammatical and makes sense. Perhaps, a better question would be: *Should we avoid it?*

Comment: It is grammatical. The question  *Should we avoid it?* will receive only opinions based on the answerer's sense of style.

Comment: Journal **of** the Convention **of** the People **of** the State **of** Indiana, to Amend the Constitution :  ...https://books.google.com/books?id=euMWAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22of+the+people+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM9Pyn0oDSAhVJWCYKHQZHC8oQ6AEIYjAM#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20people%20of%22&f=false

Comment: @TRomano A really good example.

Comment: That's the name of a journal. You can't change it.

Comment: If you have a choice of how to restructure it, you could use possessives or noun adjuncts instead, for example the "Indiana State People's Convention Journal".  Sometimes that reads better, sometimes it's less clear.

Comment: In the form presented, it seems a very formal opening or preamble to a legal document. In that vein, the formalism is more conventional. The grammar is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenters have already provided correct responses to your example.  When you are using the official name of something, just live with it, regardless of how awkward it sounds.

> ***Should*** we avoid it?

Yes, in general it is a good idea to minimize the repetition of like words in a sentence. So you should not only strive to avoid overusing **of**, but also **and**, **his**, or whatever other word finds itself used several times in a sentence. An exception would be the three articles, **a**, **an**, and **the**, simply because English grammar pretty much requires their use.

I am **not** saying *do not repeat*. But if you begin to notice you are repeating a lot of words, maybe an edit would be a good idea.